# Заменить слова из списка на другие в тексте

Tags: python, re

Имеются тексты:

```
text1 = "Шла Саша по шоссе вместе с Машей"
text2 = "Сегодня погода должна быть плохой"
text3 = "Я хочу купить торты и печенье"
```

Есть два списка:

```
spisok1 = ["Саша", "Машей", "плохой", "торты"]
spisok2 = ["Вика", "Никой", "хорошей", "фрукты"]
```

Необходимо заменить во всех текстах слова из spisok1 на слова из spisok2, чтобы получить следующий вид текстов:

```
text1 = "Шла Вика по шоссе вместе с Никой"
text2 = "Сегодня погода должна быть хорошей"
text3 = "Я хочу купить фрукты и печенье"
```

Пыталась использовать следующий код, но не получаю нужного результата

```
import re

texts = [text1, text2, text3]
new_texts = []
for text in texts:
    for word_number in range(0, len(spisok1)):
        new_text = re.sub(spisok1[word_number]), spisok2[word_number], text)
    new_texts.append(new_text)
print(new_texts)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с решением этой задачи

Comment: Обратите внимание на методы
str.maketrans()
str.translate()

Comment: я тоже думаю, что стандартных методов строк для данной задачи достаточно. Если только не задача потренироваться с регулярными выражениями

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярным выражением одним махом всю строчку:

```
_map = dict(zip(spisok1, spisok2))

regexp = "|".join(re.escape(k) for k in _map) 
new_texts = [re.sub(regexp, lambda m: _map[m.group(0)], text) for text in texts]
```

Для упрощения поиска "старое слово"->"новое слово" два списка свёл в соответствующий словарь.

Comment: а для чего Вы здесь используете _map, а не просто map?

Comment: Потому что с именем `map` в Питоне есть стандартная функция. Чтобы её ненароком не затереть и не поиметь сайд-эффектов в дальнейшем если понадобится её использовать. По той же причине, что и не называют переменные `list`, `str`, `int`, и т.д.

Comment: поняла, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Используй метод [replace](https://pythonstart.ru/string/replace-python)

Финальное решение будет выглядеть так:

```
text1 = "Шла Саша по шоссе вместе с Машей"
text2 = "Сегодня погода должна быть плохой"
text3 = "Я хочу купить торты и печенье"

spisok1 = ["Саша", "Машей", "плохой", "торты"]
spisok2 = ["Вика", "Никой", "хорошей", "фрукты"]

texts = [text1, text2, text3]

for text in texts:
    for i in range(len(spisok1)):
        text = text.replace(spisok1[i], spisok2[i])
    print(text)
```

Comment: если списки будут намного больше, то прописывать для каждого слова отдельную строку str.replace(old_word, new_word) будет затратно и сложно

Comment: А зачем прописывать для каждого? Можно просто проходить циклом по массиву со словами для замены

Comment: for i in range(len(spisok1)):
        text = text.replace(spisok1[i], spisok2[i])

Answer (score 1):

во внутреннем for замени строку

```
text = text.replace(spisok1[word_number]), spisok2[word_number])
```